# Problem with IDbConnection and StructureMap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

I have the following configured within my IContainer Initialize routine:

```
x.For<IDbConnection>().Use<SqlConnection>().Ctor<string>().Is(MY_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING);
```

Here's the constructor for my service:

```
private readonly IForumRepository _repo;
public ForumService(IForumRepository repo)
{
    _repo = repo;
}
```

And here's the constructor for my repository:

```
private readonly IDbConnection _cn;
public ForumRepository(IDbConnection connection)
{
    _cn = connection;
}
```

In one of my service routines, I am calling a method to get an object in my repository, then upon returning to the service layer I call a 2nd method in my repository - however, on this second call to the repository, my connection (_cn) no longer has a connection string associated with it (it appears to be wiped upon exiting the using {} block the first time my service called a method in the repository.

Here's the first method that I call in the repository.

```
public Tag GetTag(int id)
{
    Tag o;
    const string q = @"select * from tags where id = @pId";

    using (_cn)
    {
        _cn.Open();
        o = _cn.Query<Tag>(q, new { pId = id }).SingleOrDefault();
    } *** AT THIS POINT THE CONN STRING PROPERTY OF _CN IS CLEARED?!

    return o;
}
```

I 'd have thought this should work fine seeing as the constructor for my service instantiates a SQL Connection which the first call to the repo utilizes fine, and seeing as subsequent calls to my repo are in the same service scope I'd have thought that repository's SqlConnection dependency should still retain the original connection string details.

Can someone please shed some light on where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `using` block is finished, the object being used will be disposed.  Does the connection string get removed on disposal?  In any case, you likely shouldn't use the object after is has been disposed.

Based on the code in your post, I would think you don't want to use the `using` block?  I think you will want to manually close the connection, though (I think `using` will do that automatically as part of disposal).

Comment: Yes, the connection string is getting removed on disposal. I thought this was good practice in each of my data access methods, to wrap the db calls with a 'using', but it looks like in this scenario its not working out as the IDbConnection that is created when my repos is instantiated is essentially no good after calling 1 routine in the repos?!

Comment: Generally a using block is used when you are creating the object specifically for the block. It ensures proper disposal when you are finished with it. As long as you want to continue to access an object, you don't want to dispose it, so avoid the using block. Re-using the connection might not be the best idea anyway--it's been a while since I have hand-coded any of that but you may want to research it a bit.